# How do you break long lines in pgfgantt?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, pgfgantt

I am drawing a gantt chart using the `pgfgantt` package. I have some text in nodes that I would like to break down into multilines, but it doesn't seem to work. I made a simple example like so:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
            hgrid, 
            vgrid, 
            newline shortcut=true,
            bar label node/ .append style={align=left}
]{1}{2}
\gantttitle{aa}{2} \\
\ganttbar{%
 A very long line, A very long\ganttalignnewline
line A very long line A very long ...%
}{1}{2}
\end{ganttchart}
```

I get the error, `*"I do not know the key //pgfgantt//bar label node// .append style'"*`. The example is almost copy-and-paste from an example in the pgfgantt manual.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Can you post on this properly as an answer, so that I can mark it as best answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

PGFkeys doesn’t allow spaces between `/` and `.append style`.

It doesn’t allow spaces around the path separator `/` at all. Here it tries to find a key `␣.append style`, a value of that name and finally a handler of that name but doesn’t find anything, of course.

Remove the the space and you are fine.